# Is there any data repository of discontinued commercial routes?

Tags: commercial-aviation, datasets, flight-path

Is there any way of knowing - for example by referring to an existing data repository or something similar - what commercial routes were operated from a given airport in a given year?

This would be a list of all commercial routes that have been discontinued.

Comment: Something like [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org/) / [OpenFlights Data](http://openflights.org/data.html), [FlightAware](http://flightaware.com/) / [FlightAware Commercial](http://flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/), [FlightStats](https://www.flightstats.com/) / [FlightStats Developer Center](https://developer.flightstats.com/) or [OAG Historical Flight Status](http://www.oag.com/Flight-Status/Historical-Flight-Status)?

Comment: Do you mean flight plan routes, or service between airports?

Comment: Services between airports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[departedflights.com](http://www.departedflights.com/) has a list of historical routes both by [airlines](http://www.departedflights.com/routemaps.html) and (a few) [hubs](http://www.departedflights.com/airlinehubs.html). Though it is not complete, it has a lot of data.